# Migrate Custom Field Renderer from Django 1.8 to Django 3.2

Tags: django, forms, widget, render

I am trying to migrate a custom field renderer in a Django 1.8 form to Django 3.2.

The form looks like this:

```
class SomeEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    job_uuid=forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    class Meta:
        model=Job
        fields=('status',)
        widgets={'status': forms.RadioSelect(renderer=BSRadioFieldRenderer)}
```

So as it seems there is no Rendermixin anymore which accepts a renderer in its def **init**(). I have read the new source code and see that RadioSelect is now a subclass of ChoiceWidget. I cant get my head around to inject my old renderer into the new structure.

Can someone please point me into the right direction?

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a hacky way which works...
Just subclass forms.RadioSelect and accept the renderer kwarg like this:

```
class CustomRadioSelect(forms.RadioSelect):
    def __init__(self, renderer=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(forms.RadioSelect, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class SomeEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    job_uuid=forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    class Meta:
        model=Job
        fields=('status',)
        widgets = {'status': CustomRadioSelect(renderer=BSRadioFieldRenderer)}
```

Please note that these classes are truncated and I only wrote those parts in here which are relevant to the problem I had.